# Replace text to emoticon (on Forumotion)

Tags: javascript, jquery, emoticons

Forumotion has a limit of kb that the emoticon have, that make impossible many 50 x 50 gifs to be put.

A person give me a ccode, but it replace the text for a image by the img alt, and it replaces every image on forum with the same value on alt. So, i want to do it by text (And turn possible add more emoticons)

Here's the code:

```
var Smileys;

Smileys = {
'Xuxa mandando beijo' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/xuxa2_zps1da72f7f.gif',
'Nazaré Tedesco' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/naza1_zps357c14c3.gif', 
'Tiffany Pollard' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/ny04-2_zpse5e92df0.gif',
'Tiffany' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/ny012_zpsa64e9a2e.gif',
'Tiff' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/ny01_zps22380ffc.gif',
'Ines Brasil' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/ines_zps10449d33.gif',
'Xuxa' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/XUXY_zpsfdecaffd.gif',
'Eita' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/susto_zpsfb783142.gif',
'Sofrendo' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/17_zps45611787.gif',
'Lara com Z' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/Lara7_zps32c7c5d6.gif',
'666' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/666_zps88fd6d96.gif',
'Xuxa chorando' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/1CHORO_zpscc0f91e1.gif',
'Puta que pariu' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/putaquepariu_zpsbcd6baa1.gif',
'Gretchen' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/gretchensaindo_zpsbb7eafc6.gif',
'eliana nojo' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/eliananojo_zpsc1660c97.gif',
'Sônia Abrão' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/sonia_zpsd5b4b8d9.gif',
'Mas não se irrite' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/semquererr_zpsbff4f60f.gif',
'Falta de sacanagem' : 'http://i738.photobucket.com/albums/xx29/forummultix/emoticons/putafaltadesacanagem_zps162a2df9.gif',
};

$(function() {
$.each(Smileys, function(key, value) {
    $('img[alt="' + key + '"]').attr('src', value);
});
});
```